# Almacenar variable para reutilizar constantemente - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy ingresando al desarrollo ASP.net MVC 5 y tengo una consulta, cual sería la forma mas óptima de almacenar variables obtenidas al inicial sesión y poder reutilizarlas constantemente en el los diversos módulos de mi app web.

Lo vengo realizando de esta manera pero al pasar los minutos (5 - 8') se vuelven vacías las variables que asigne al principio y se cae mi aplicación.

1. Si el login es OK seteo las variables.

{

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(m.xCodigoUsuario, true);
                    VariableGlobal.sNombreUsuario = data[0]["NO_TRAB"].ToString();
                    VariableGlobal.sGrupoUsuario = data[0]["CO_GRUP"].ToString();
                    VariableGlobal.scoTrabajador = data[0]["CO_TRAB"].ToString();
                    VariableGlobal.scoUsua = data[0]["CO_USUA"].ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Principal");
```

2. Mi clase creada:

   class VariableGlobal
   {
       private static string NombreUsuario = "";

   ```
   public static string sNombreUsuario
   {
       get { return NombreUsuario; }
       set { NombreUsuario = value; }
   }

   private static string GrupoUsuario = "";

   public static string sGrupoUsuario
   {
       get { return GrupoUsuario; }
       set { GrupoUsuario = value; }
   }

   private static string codEmpresa = "";

   public static string scodEmpresa
   {
       get { return codEmpresa; }
       set { codEmpresa = value; }
   }

   private static string codUnidad = "";

   public static string scodUnidad
   {
       get { return codUnidad; }
       set { codUnidad = value; }
   }

   private static string coTrabajador = "";

   public static string scoTrabajador
   {
       get { return coTrabajador; }
       set { coTrabajador = value; }
   }

   private static string coUsua = "";

   public static string scoUsua
   {
       get { return coUsua; }
       set { coUsua = value; }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar variables de sesion Session["sNombreUsuario "] = data[0]["NO_TRAB"].ToString(); por defecto una variable de sesion en MVC dura 20 minutos sin uso pero ese valor lo puedes configurar en el WebConfig.